# 2 mice and keyboards on one PC?

Tags: keyboard, mouse

Is it possible to have two mice and two keyboards work for one PC?  I have a wireless keyboard and mouse that I've been using for quite some time and love them, however they stink for gaming.  I wanna keep the wireless set up for the Office functions on it and for when I run the PC to the TV and am sitting on the couch.  I want a small wired keyboard and mouse on the desk at all times for PC gaming.  I've got the necessary PS/2 ports and enough USB ports to run everything USB if I had to.  I was just wondering if the extra inputs would cause conflicts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, they will work together while all plugged in at the same time.

Tried and tested.

Comment: agree, do this often myself, mixed combinations of wired and wireless mice and keyboards.

Comment: I bet this feature plus a wireless mouse or keyboard (or both!) could be used for very nice pranks on your colleagues. Ideally when sitting behind them... :-)

Comment: Just curious: how does the caps lock work then?

Comment: I think results will vary depending on the hardware really.  I just hooked a keyboard up to my laptop and caps lock (+ the LED) syncs between the two keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep your ps/2 port connected mouse and keyboard plugged in, and plug in a usb keyboard and/or mouse.

The only conflicts come if someone starts using those while you are using the others, then your mouse gets very jumpy and your emails sttartta to looookkk likeekeke thtiiiiis.

Answer (score 1):

You can have as many as you like and as many ports you have available... :)